# How to add paging in Datalist in ASP.NEt?

Tags: datalist

How to add paging in Datalist in ASP.NEt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these articles:

1. [Efficient Data Paging with the ASP.NET 2.0 DataList Control and ObjectDataSource](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/07/434787.aspx) (Scott Guthrie)
2. [Adding Paging Support to the Repeater or DataList with the PagedDataSource Class](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx)