# manual gridview paging

Tags: asp.net

i'm am pulling 10 out of 100 records back from the database and placing into gridview (no datasource objects here).

how do i enable paging that comes with the gridview? I know the total records is 100 can I use that somehow to activate the paging?

I know I can do this easily with DataSource objects but was just wondering if I could do it completely manually as far as the GridView is concerned.

**Markup**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        onsorting="GridView1_Sorting">
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
</form>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = GetCustomers();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**strong text**

Comment: why not use the inbuilt paging in the gridview. set PageSize to 10 for the gridview and for the datasource pull all 100 records

Comment: because on the data access i want pull only 10 records at a time

Comment: Take a look at related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966799/how-to-add-paging-in-datalist-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostback) {BindData();}
}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
     GridView1.DataSource = GetCustomers();
     GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
     GridView1.DataBind();

}

void BindData()
{
   GridView1.DataSource = GetCustomers();
   GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Also you need to add this to gridview markup:

```
OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
```